# Opening chrome should cause the extension to check the output of an API.How can this be possible?

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

Hi I am developing a website as my chrome extension.the extension periodically checks the output of a server file and then works according to the output of the server file.Now what I need is that presently it checks the output of the server file every 5 min.So what I need is that when the output of the server file changes at any time,at that moment I have to do some operations.How can I do this? 
Here is my background.js

```
var myNotificationID = null;
var oldChromeVersion = !chrome.runtime;
chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function (){ 
 updateIcon();
 });
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (){ 
 updateIcon();
    });
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (){ 
      updateIcon();
    });
 function getGmailUrl() {
  return "http://calpinemate.com/";
}

function isGmailUrl(url) {
  return url.indexOf(getGmailUrl()) == 0;
}
 chrome.windows.onCreated.addListener(function (){ 
  updateIcon();
   });
function onInit() {
  updateIcon();
  if (!oldChromeVersion) { 
    chrome.alarms.create('watchdog',{periodInMinutes:5,delayInMinutes:  0});
  }
}

function onAlarm(alarm) {
  if (alarm && alarm.name == 'watchdog') {
    onWatchdog();
  } 
  else {
    updateIcon();
  }
}

function onWatchdog() {
  chrome.alarms.get('refresh', function(alarm) {
  if (alarm) {
    console.log('Refresh alarm exists. Yay.');
  } 
  else {
    updateIcon();  
  }
});
}
if (oldChromeVersion) {
  updateIcon();
  onInit();
} 
else {
 chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);
 chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(onAlarm);
 }
```

It is the updateIcon() which reads the server file.And when there is change in the output of server file,I have to call the updateIcon() itself.Presently only in every 5 min,the output is checked and updated in extension.But I need it to happen  at the moment the status of server file changes.Anyone please help me.
In short,what I need is that when the output of API changes at any time at that time I have to call updateIcon().

Here is my updateIcon()

```
function updateIcon(){
  var urlPrefix = 'http://www.calpinemate.com/employees/attendanceStatus/';
  var urlSuffix = '/2';
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {    
       var item=req.responseText;


       if(item==1){

        .....//something   
      }

      else{
         // do something  
      } 
   else {

        alert("ERROR: status code " + req.status);

       }
      }
       });
    var url = urlPrefix + encodeURIComponent(localStorage.username) + urlSuffix;
    req.open("GET", url);
     req.send(null);     
   }
```

I need to periodically monitor the API for output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a **[WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)** to maintain a persistent, two-way channel between the server and your extension.

**But**, considering that PHP does not have native support for WebSockets (i.e. you would need to use an external library) and the fact that the interaction will be infrequent (only at log-in/-out), it might be unnecessary overhead.

I suggest you communicate the login-status directly from your web-page to your extension. For a more detailed description of the process, see **[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140020/how-to-track-session-of-a-browser-from-chrome-extension#answer-20140998)** to one similar question of yours.

---

**UPDATE:**
Since it turned out you don't have control of the domain you need to "monitor", there is unfortunately no other option (that I know of) than polling at frequent intervals on that server-resource.

If you are using a non-persistent background-page (which is advisable due to its resource-friendliness) you must use the **[`chrome.alarms` API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html)**, which allows [at most 1 triggering per minute](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/alarms.html#method-create): (*in order to reduce the load on the user's machine* - note: to help debug your extension, this limit is no imposed on unpacked extensions).

If you decide to use a persistent background-page, you can use `setInterval()` with an arbitrarily smal period (in milliseconds):

```
setInterval(function() {
    /* Check up on the server */
    ...
}, 30000);   // <-- trigger every 30.000 milliseconds (== 30 seconds)
```

Comment: HI i have updated my answer.Now it just works fine on opening a new window or tab.Now I need to make it work on the existing tab.Can you Please check my code.

Comment: I know you do not like it, but my answer to your question in the above. If you want to have real-time update, you need to follow my suggestion. Your updated code just checks the server every time any window or tab is created and every time any tab is updated (but that is definitely not real-time).

Comment: hey but the website that I am retrieving is not under my control.So I can't change the code.That's why I use this.Is there any other way?

Comment: Ooops, I thought it was under your control. I will revise my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it out and (as usual) don't forget to accept/upvote it if you find it appropriate ;)

Comment: Hey I am using non-persistent background.So where should I put your code?

Comment: Sorry i am not able to upvote.becoz i don't have 15 reputation.But i have accepted your answer and thankyou once again

Comment: Always glad to help :) (If you really want to upvote it you can always use your other account. (BTW, why the multiple accounts ?))

Comment: because i can't ask any more questions using the previous account.that's why.all my privileges lost

Comment: Why not ? What did you do ?

Comment: NO idea,what is the matter.When I tried to post question,such a message is shown to me.ie,i no longer can post questions..

Comment: hey can you please check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489980/how-to-develop-a-simple-add-on-on-firefox-which-when-clicked-just-navigates-to-a

Comment: I think you are familiar with my tasks..just like i added my website as chrome extension,I also need it to be set as firefox add-ons.do u have any idea?

Comment: I have no idea about FF add-ons. Sorry.